# Angular Datatables - Refresh Table

Tags: angular, datatables, angular-datatables

I am using `angular-datatables` in my Angular app. I need to refresh the datatable when data changes (say, when a form is filled and submitted). The equivalent jQuery code is

`$('#my-datatable').DataTable.ajax.reload()`.

I am using Angular 7. And here is the [link](https://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/getting-started) of the library that I am using.

Comment: I strongly suggest you to not use that library. It uses jquery and using jquery is not good pratices in angular apps. There a lot of libraries that provide table functionalities

Comment: @devpato, kindly direct me to the libraries you are talking about in the comment above

Comment: @devpato, on the similar stackoverflow answer you've provided, seems it's using jQuery of which I could simply do `$('#my-datatable').DataTable.ajax.reload()` and it's working.

Comment: https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/table
https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview

Answer (score 5):

`dtInstance.ajax.reload()`. You can create a reload() function.

Try like this:

```
import { DataTableDirective } from 'angular-datatables';

dtElement: DataTableDirective;
dtInstance: Promise<DataTables.Api>;

reload() {
  this.dtElement.dtInstance.then((dtInstance: DataTables.Api) => {
    dtInstance.ajax.reload()
  });
}
```

Comment: how does it identify a particular datatable? Say I have multiple datatables in the same page

Comment: You need to use `@ViewChildren(DataTableDirective);  dtElements: QueryList<DataTableDirective>`

Comment: And  this.dtElements.forEach((dtElement: DataTableDirective) => {
    
        // Get the instance and do your stuff

    });

Comment: If you provide a  stackbiltz,can show working demo as I didn't try the above code in the comment. In one of my projects I created 3 child component for 3 tables to avoid this scenerio